# How can we interpret such weird values of the Adjusted Rand Index?

Tags: classification, python, clustering, scikit-learn, metric

I'm using `scikit-learn` to compute the *Adjusted Rand Index* for a binary classifier where the two labels are $\{0, 255\}$ (binary images). According to the ARI's documentation found [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.adjusted_rand_score.html), the ARI should take values in $[-1, 1]$. However, I'm getting very weird results as can be seen in the attached screenshot.

How can we interpret such results? Is there some normalization that needs to be applied here?

Many thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: According the documentation you linked, ARI should lie in [-1,1].

Comment: Yes, sorry! Fixing it.

Comment: Hi, the upper bound is 1, but the lower bound is negative and dependent on the number of nodes. You’re getting impossible results like 176.71, so this suggests a bug in how you’re calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

The upper bound is 1, but the lower bound is negative and dependent on the number of nodes. Any negative value suggests that the two clusterings that you’re comparing have less in common than they would by random chance.

You’re getting impossible results like 176.71, so this suggests a bug in how you’re calling the function.

Answer (score -1):

This [article](https://mk-hasan.github.io/posts/2020/04/blog-post-4/) explains what ARI is and why it is between [-1, 1]. Check it out, it is a great read!

To put it briefly, ARI takes on the value of 1 when y_pred perfectly matches y_test. ARI is 0 when the number of matches between y_pred and y_test equals the number of matches we would have gotten if we would have randomly chosen a label for each datapoint in y_pred. And ARI would be -1 is we got all predicted labels wrong.

The values you got mean you have an error in your code because like you mentioned ARI takes on values between [-1, 1]. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, welcome to CV! Could you please add the reference for the paper you mention in case the link dies in the future? Thanks!